# Replace character in CSV-string that is LIKE the separator, but not THE separator

Tags: php, string, csv, substr

I have a little problem with working on strings in PHP.

Imagine a CSV file with these fields:

```
ItemID;ItemText;ItemVAT;ItemEAN;
```

Clearly, the separator in this string is ";". The problem is, that values from "ItemText" *might* contain the ";", too.

I need to filter these strings and replace the containing ";" with something else, like "#" or "$", doesn't matter. I tried counting the ";" with `substr_count` to determine if I *have* an additional ";" (in comparision to the count of a "normal" value string). But I don't know how to find the actual ";" in the value. To make things harder, there can be more than one ";" in the value string.

Anyone got some ideas how to filter these unnecessary ";"?

Comment: There is no real way to do this in general unless you know the format of every field. I am guessing ItemText is the only field that could contain extra `;`'s?

Comment: Yes, ItemText is the only one that can contain the extra `;`.

Comment: Okay Then find the index of the first `;` . The next `k-4` semicolons after that one are extraneous, where `k` is the number of semicolons in the string.

Comment: You can make a separator with more than 1 characters |*| :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. @Shibi I get the CSV in this format from an API. I have no influence on the used separator.

Comment: Did you try to read it with standard php function? http://www.php.net/fgetcsv  - it will solve all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you have this fields always.

```
$line = "34;erwffw;wefweef;fwe3242;23342;53453;";
$toArray = explode(";", $line);
$counntSemi = count($toArray);

$newLine[0] = $toArray[0]; // ItemID
$newLine[1] = ''; // ItemText
$newLine[2] = $toArray[$counntSemi-3]; // ItemVAT
$newLine[3] = $toArray[$counntSemi-2]; // ItemEAN

// ItemText filter
for($i=1; $i < ($counntSemi-3); $i++) {
    $newLine[1] .= $toArray[$i]."@"; 
}

print_r($newLine);
// here you can implode this newLine with the semicolons
```

Answer (score 0):

When a field contains the separator, then it should be quoted, like

```
valueA;"valueB;with;embedded;separators";valueC
```

If this is the case you can e.g. merge each array item with the following while it contains an odd nr of '"' characters.

If the creator of the file (the encoder of the data) did not follow that rule then there's no generic way to decode the file correctly because encoding the values "A" and "B;C" would produce the same csv file as encoding the values "A;B" and "C". In that case you can only blame the creator or try to identify ItemVAT based on a pattern you it has